# C# Sieve of Eratosthenes

Tags: c#, primes

I have written this code to find prime numbers, and it works well, but the calculation speeds are incredibly slow..... Am I doing this wrong? I know that I might be really doing this the wrong way, but please help me! Thank you very much!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Primenumbers
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {    
            List<int> NoPrime = new List<int>();

            for(int x = 2; x < 10000;x++)
            {
                for(int y = x * 2;y < 10000;y = y + x)
                {    
                    if(!NoPrime.Contains(y))
                    {
                        NoPrime.Add(y);
                    }    
                }    
            }

            for(int z = 2; z < 10000;z++)
            {
                if(!NoPrime.Contains(z))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(z);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
This is the new code, I changed 'List' to 'HashSet' and added a counter to get the sum of all the prime numbers. A big thank you to everyone who commented/answered, you guys are awesome!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class MainClass
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        HashSet<int> NoPrime = new HashSet<int>();

        long count = 0;
        int n = 2000000;

        for(int x = 2; x < n;x++)
        {
            for(int y = x * 2;y < n;y = y + x)
            {

            if(!NoPrime.Contains(y))
            {
                NoPrime.Add(y);
            }
        }

        for(int z = 2; z < n;z++)
        {
            if(!NoPrime.Contains(z))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(z);
                count = count + z;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Sum is: " + count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use HashSet not List..

Comment: Contains does a linear search. I recommend using an array. More memory used but much faster.

Comment: This question might be more suitable for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Neolisk Array is the same as List that is currently used.

Comment: @Ondra: No it isn't.  List uses an array for internal storage, true, but it's sparse in terms of the prime/non-prime numbers.  The array is dense, which makes finding a particular element trivial and fast.

Comment: @ondra: I did not mean using array.contains. I meant checking 0 or 1 at the index. For example a (4) = 0 means 4 is not prime. a (5) = 1 means 5 is prime.

Comment: Note: the algorithm actually defines better version than you have in your edit - see my update answer - you are running inner loop for non-prime x'es. It really does not make huge difference for such low numbers as you have in your sample so it is ok in practice, but may give you lower mark if it was an assignment.

Comment: @Neolisk I see. One more improvement - you don´t need to check anythink in that case, just store the value. (The same probably applies for HashSet)

Comment: @Ondra: I am fairly positive that a hash set would check existance of the element before adding it. Otherwise how does it return True or False depending on if element was actually added? The benefit of using array is exactly what you mentioned - there is no "existance" check.

Comment: I agree. The point was, that you don´t have to do the check by yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Complexity of your code is between O(n * (n log n)) and O(n ^ 3) (not exactly sure) instead of O(n log log n) (see [Sieve of Eratosthenes: Complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Algorithm_complexity) ). The higher complexity caused by

- linear search in `NoPrime` list (give an extra `n` to complexity)
- lack of "find next prime" check in outer loop - so inner loop have complexity of more than O(log log n)

To fix:

Change to `Dictionary<int,bool>` (or better yet to `HashSet<int>` as suggested in comments) to get O(1) complexity for `Contains`. Alternatively you can implement algorithm directly by per-allocating large array of `bool` for each number and  mark items `true` (again giving O(1) check if number is prime or not).

Add check in outer loop to skip inner iteration where x is not prime.

Comment: I actually just changed 'List' to 'HashSet' and this solved, the program prints out all the prime numbers under 2 million in just 15,75 seconds, thank you very much, all of you!

Comment: why N^2? with O(1) `Contains` (and `Add`) it's N*log(N).

Comment: @WillNess - thanks for reminder that complexity is actually better than O(n^2) due to variable step of inner loop. Note that it actually even better - `log log n`, not just `log n` according to Wikipedia.

Comment: I was talking about the OP code (fixed to O(1) access). It's in N*log(N), ecause it doesn't enumerate primes, but rather *all* numbers. With O(N) access it's in N^2*log(N). It can be easily measured, with [empirical orders of growth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth).

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace primefinder2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //edited version of Alexander Ameye's code (https://stackoverflow.com/users/4014883/alexander-ameye)
            HashSet<int> NoPrime = new HashSet<int>();
        long count = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("please enter a max search value");
        bool input = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int n);
        while (input == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{input} is not a valid value.\nPlease enter a valid number");
            input = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out n);

        }
        string name = $"Primes_to_{n}";
        string filename = String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm}__{1}", DateTime.Now, name);
        for (int x = 2; x < n; x++)
        {
            for (int y = x * 2; y < n; y = y + x)
            {

                if (!NoPrime.Contains(y))
                {
                    NoPrime.Add(y);
                }

            }

        }

        for (int z = 2; z < n; z++)
        {
            if (!NoPrime.Contains(z))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(z);
                using (System.IO.StreamWriter file =
        new System.IO.StreamWriter($@"{filename}.csv", true))
                {
                    file.WriteLine(z);
                }
                count = count + z;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"Sum is: {count}");
        Console.ReadLine();


    }
}
}
```

I made some slight edits to the code to allow for user determined search length and for the primes to be written to a CSV for future reference.
let me know how I did and if there is anything i can fix with regards to my edits.