# Filter a list of integers based on integer multiples - C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to filter a list of `int` based on multiples of a specific number, but I am not sure how to do this.  I have searched this forum and found nothing related, but apologies in advance if I'm wrong.

Here is my code:

```
int val = 28;

List<int> divisible = new List<int>();

for (int i = 1; i <= val; i++) {
                divisible.Add(i);
}

foreach(var d in divisible)
{
     if(val % d == 0)
     {
         // do something
     }
     else
     {
      // get rid of all multiples of the number that "val" is not divisible by
     }
}
```

Basically, this code should create a divisible list from `1` to `28`.  If `val` is divisible by one of the numbers in the list, thats fine, but if it falls into `else`, I want to be able to filter out all multiples of that number out of the current list we are looping through.

The next number that wouldn't be divisible would be `3` in this example, so in the `else` get rid of `6`, `9`, `12`, `...` etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if number is prime number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15743192/check-if-number-is-prime-number)

Comment: Or more precisely you probably want Sieve of Eratosthenes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25702173/c-sharp-sieve-of-eratosthenes

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, but you're just missing the actual code to remove the item. But there is a caveat: You cannot modify a list when you are looping through it using `foreach`. There are a couple ways to handle that:

1. Depending on your requirements, maybe just don't add them in the first place. Move your `val % d == 0` condition into the `for` loop that adds the values, and just don't add the values that are divisible by `d`.
2. Make a new list (`List<int> toRemove`) where you keep track of all the values you need to remove. After you're done the `foreach` loop, loop through your `toRemove` list and use [`divisible.Remove(value)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.remove?view=netframework-4.8) to remove those.
3. Change your `foreach` to a `for` loop, which will allow you to use [`divisible.RemoveAt(i)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeat?view=netframework-4.8). But you will have to make sure you don't skip a value on the next iteration of the `for` loop (since removing a value changes the size of the list).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Gabriel.  You cannot alter a underlying enumeration while traversing it with with foreach.  The easiest thing to do would be to convert it to a for loop.

Also in the initial population of your list try using the newer way

```
var divisible = Enumerable.Range(1, val).ToList();
```

then do

```
for(int 0 = 1; i < val; i++)
{
    if(val % d == 0)
    {
       // do something
    }
    else
    {
       divisible.RemoveAt(i);
    }
 }
```